# Objective-C: making documentation

Tags: objective-c, xcode, documentation-generation

I've been developing for Visual Studio and C# for a long time. Now, I'm developing with XCode and Objective-C.

On C# I can use `/// <summary>` to generate documentation. **Is there any kind of mechanism like that on XCode to generate documentation?** And **what kind of comments should I use?**

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl)? That claims to support Objective-C. There's even a [walkthrough](http://developer.apple.com/tools/creatingdocsetswithdoxygen.html) on ADC.

Comment: What kind of comments should I use?

Comment: @VansFannel: Doxygen comments. Read the Doxygen documentation: http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/docblocks.html

Comment: +1 for Doxygen — it ain't perfect, but it's quite respectable. Since Apple uses HeaderDoc for generating much of their docs, using compatible comment styles is most consistent. I tend to use `/*! ... */` myself.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [AppleDoc](http://github.com/tomaz/appledoc) to render your Doxygen comments into a style usable by Xcode

Comment: Ive been using a combination of appledoc and doxygen for a while. Works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need [HeaderDoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HeaderDoc) which is recommended by Apple for code documentation.

Here's an example.

```
/*!
 This is a method.

 @param    param1    This is first parameter.

 @result
 This method returns nothing.

 @discussion
 This is an example.


 */
- (void)someMethodWithParam1:(NSInteger)param1
{
}
```

Manual: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/intro/intro.html

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Skeet said, the most popular method is Doxygen, and from what I can tell so far, the comment formatting is basically interoperable with AppleDoc.

Also be sure to check out the comment generator plugin that Fred McCann wrote:
http://www.duckrowing.com/2011/05/14/using-the-doxygen-helper-in-xcode-4/

He also has a great how-to post for writing Doxygen comments:
http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-i/

(This would be better as a comment to Jon's answer, but alas I don't have the points.)

Answer (score 0):

As a said, my fav pattern :)

```
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
   /// \brief setX
   /// \param x offset of the image.
   /// \return a new image as an QImage.
   /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    QImage  setX(int x);
```